# How to apply Python Functions over Airflow XCom_pull value within Airflow Operator

Tags: python, airflow

I have a requirement where i need to capture XCOM response over Airflow SQLsensor operator and apply some python command to change data format.

code which i have is given below:-

```
delta_sql_sensor_task = SqlSensor( 
    task_id= "Verify-Completion-of-Delta-Job", 
    poke_interval= 10, 
    timeout=100,
    conn_id="lct_statedb",
    #gobal_id_list="{{ str(ti.xcom_pull(key='id_list', task_ids=['hook_task'])).replace('[','') }}",
    sql="SELECT COALESCE ( (SELECT count(*)  FROM lct_transformation_history WHERE deltaload_transformation_status is not null AND fullload_transformation_status is not null AND category='sites' AND id in (" + "{{ (ti.xcom_pull(key='id_list', task_ids=['hook_task'])) }}" + ") group by category),0) AS TRIGGER;",
    trigger_rule='one_failed',
    dag=dag)
```

Response which i receive from the code `"{{ (ti.xcom_pull(key='id_list', task_ids=['hook_task'])).str() }}"`  is as `([('13',)],)` but i need to change response response to `'13'`

Following Options which i tried are given below:-

1. I tried to store xcom_pull response in a Global variable `gobal_id_list` and apply Python functions but it didn't worked.
2. I also tried to apply Python operator within SQL variable as given below but no luck, code given below :-
   `sql="SELECT COALESCE ( (SELECT count(*)  FROM lct_transformation_history WHERE deltaload_transformation_status is not null AND fullload_transformation_status is not null AND category='sites' AND id in (" + "{{ str(ti.xcom_pull(key='id_list', task_ids=['hook_task'])).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace('(','').replace(')','').replace(',,','') }}" + ") group by category),0) AS TRIGGER;",`.

Looking forward for valuable input.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem with following solution, since my Xcom response was in tuple & list hence i solved through a code change given below :-

```
"{{ (ti.xcom_pull(key='id_list', task_ids=['hook_task'])).str()[0][0][0] }}
```

and it gave me desired result what i was expecting as `13`.